# Manually resize column width after report is rendered on the browser

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to let user resize the column width after report is rendered on browser?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. Once the report is rendered it is basically static (there are a couple of interactivity options, like sorting columns). You need to set the column width to an appropriate value up front, however (if allowed by your report server configuration) your users can export the report to Excel and adjust column widths there if required.

Answer (score 0):

One sort of a hack way to do this would be to first include various widths of the same column and hide all but one based on a hidden parameter value. Then add a `Jump to Report` Action on the headers that reload the report with the updated parameter value.

For example, if you had 3 different column widths available for Column1, the value passed in the `Jump to Report` Action would be something like `=iif(Parameters!Column1Width.Value + 1 > 3,1,Parameters!.Column1Width.Value + 1)`. Then set the Hidden attribute on the 3 Column1 columns to `=Parameters!Column1Width.Value <> 1`, `=Parameters!Column1Width.Value <> 2`, and `=Parameters!Column1Width.Value <> 3` respectively.